# Reading and correctly understanding/interpreting control characters from a file (python)

Tags: python, csv, controls, character

I'm a python beginner and just ran into a simple problem: I have a list of names (designators) and then a very simple code that reads lines in a csv file and prints the csv lines that has a name in the first column (row[0]) in common with my "designator list". So:

```
import csv

DesignatorList = ["AAX-435", "AAX-961", "HHX-9387", "HHX-58", "K-58", "K-14", "K-78524"]

with open('DesignatorFile.csv','rb') as FileReader:
    for row in csv.reader(FileReader, delimiter=';'):
        if row[0] in DesignatorList:
            print row
```

My csv files is only a list of names, like this:

```
AAX-435
AAX-961
HHX-58
HHX-9387
```

I would like to be able to use wildcards like * and ., example: let's say that I put this on my csv file:

```
AAX*
H.X-9387
*58
```

I need my code to be able to interpret those wild cards/control characters, printing the following:

- every line that starts with "AAX";
- every line that starts with "H", then any following character, then finally ends with "X-9387";
- every line that ends with "58".

Thank you!

---

**EDIT:** For future reference (in case somebody runs into the same problem), this is how I solved my problem following [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133649/roman-susi) advice:

```
import csv
import re
DesignatorList = ["AAX-435", "AAX-961", "HHX-9387", "HHX-58", "K-58", "K-14", "K-78524"]
with open('DesignatorFile.txt','rb') as FileReader:
    for row in csv.reader(FileReader, delimiter=';'):
        designator_col0 = row[0]
        designator_col0_re = re.compile("^" + ".*".join(re.escape(i) for i in designator_col0.split("*")) + "$")
        for d in DesignatorList:
            if designator_col0_re.match(d):
                print d
```

Comment: Try looking into regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

You may need to prepare regular expression (regex) for use by replacing '*' with '.*' and adding ^ (beginning of a string) and $ (end of string) to the beginning and the end of the regular expression. In addition, you may need to escape everything else by re.escape function (that is, function escape from module re).

In case you do not have any other "control characters" (as you call them), splitting the string by "*" and joining by ".*" after applying escape.

For example,

```
import re
def make_rule(rule):  # where rule for example "H*X-9387" 
   return re.compile("^" + ".*".join(re.escape(i) for i in rule.split("*")) + "$")
```

Then you can match (I guess, your rule is row):

```
...
rule_re = make_rule(row)
for d in DesignatorList:
    if rule_re.match(d):
        print row  # or maybe print d
```

(I have understood, that rules are coming from CSV file while designators are from a list. It's easy to do it the other way around).

The examples above are examples. You still need to adapt them into your program.

Comment: Saved my life, man, THANK YOU! Just for future reference (in case anybody runs into the same problem in the future), just edited the original message showing my new code. Thanks again Roman!

Answer (score 0):

Python's string object does have a `startswith` and an `endswith` method, which you could use here if you only had a small number of rules.  The most general way to go with this, since you seem to have fairly simple patterns, is [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).  That way you can encode those rules as patterns.

```
import re
rules = ['^AAX.*$', # starts with AAX
         '^H.*X-9387$', # starts with H, ends with X-9387
         '^.*58$'] # ends with 58

for line in reader:
    if any(re.match(rule, line) for rule in rules):
        print line
```